# Who is Tak Kovacs’ partner in S01E01?

Tags: character-identification, altered-carbon

In the first opening scene of S01E01 of *Altered Carbon*, Tak Kovacs in his birth sleeve is with a white woman in some sort of bedroom or hotel. They are attacked by CTAC and she appears to be real killed in front of him by Jaeger. Tak seems to have cared about her, at least in that moment.

Who is she? Is she just a throwaway character or do we expect to see her again?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The character is Sarah Sachilowski. In the book series she is Kovacs's partner (both romantic and business) on Harlan's World and has run several illegal jobs with him, culminating in her body-death alongside Kovacs at the hands of the local security forces.

It is important to note that Sarah is a much more important character in the books, and does not suffer real death (i.e. stack death) in the opening scene as she does in the Netflix series.

In the books she is referenced multiple times over the three books. However, her role seems to have been merged with that of other characters in the Netflix series.

Answer (score 3):

According to [IMDb](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt5989942/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_tt_cl_sc) and the [fandom.com episode page](https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Out_of_the_Past) the character's name is ["Sarah"](https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Sarah).

She appears to be a one-off character, since she has no other listed appearances (through 2 seasons).  (She hasn't even been given a last name.)

Note that the CTAC commando leader Jaeger blows out her stack, which amounts to real death in-universe, so it's pretty clear she's not coming back.